# AngularJS-Switching between Pages after Certain Time Limit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I searched around StackOverflow already but I was unable to find an adequate solution to what I'm looking for, so I will ask the question again. I'm trying to create a certain app that starts off with a "splash page" with some cool pictures, etc., but after a certain time--say 4 seconds--it will transition to the next page. How can I do this? I read some stuff up about the timeout() function but couldn't really understand it.

I'm thinking for some sort of timing function that when time expires, it activates ui-sref or href to go to the next page. By the way, I'm kinda an AngularJS newbie so don't judge please :)
If you want me to post some code I can do so but I don't really have an idea of where to start...just have some template stuff for both pages.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inject $state and $timeout into the controller on the splash page you can have a function.

```
function activate (){
  $timeout(function(){
    $state.go('page2')
  },4000)
}
activate();
```

You could also not have a redirect but rather a popup on your main page which goes away after 4 seconds so that you dont need to redirect but I dont know how your application is designed.

This is assuming you have some routes set up also

Comment: Yes I have routes and controllers set up...I tried to integrate your code into my code but it didn't seem to do anything? Is there another way to do this? Thanks a lot for helping btw

Comment: could you post a code snippet of the controller please

Answer (score 1):

> I'm thinking for some sort of timing function that when time expires, it activates ui-sref or href to go to the next page.

This is exactly what `$timeout()` is. When you pass it a function and a timeout (in milliseconds), it will run that function after the specified milliseconds have elapsed.

So,

```
$timeout(function() {
    $state.go('page2');
}, 4000);
```

will call the function (go to page2) after a timeout of 4 seconds (4000ms). Lines of code after $timeout() will execute immediately (i.e. not wait for the timeout).

You can just put this code at the start of your splash page's controller. Make sure you have $state and $timeout injected.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a simple barebones Angular application that does what you want. Keep in mind I use the routeProvider module instead of the stateProvider, however the same principle applies.

I have put together a [live Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2PMFVQRXvJzMJNYVHXUA?p=preview) demo for you. For more information on how to use $timeout click [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout).

The relevant part is:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $location) {
  // Main controller

  $scope.title = "First Page";

  var goToSecondPage = function() {
    $location.path('/second');
  };

  $timeout(goToSecondPage, 5000);
});
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $location) {
  // Main controller

  $scope.title = "First Page";

  var goToSecondPage = function() {
    $location.path('/second');
  };

  $timeout(goToSecondPage, 5000);
});

app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $location) {
  // Second controller

  $scope.title = "Second Page";

  var goToMainPage = function() {
    $location.path('/');
  };

  $timeout(goToMainPage, 5000);
});

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: "main.tpl.html",
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/second', {
            templateUrl: "second.tpl.html",
            controller: 'SecondCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>My Angular App</h1>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </body>

</html>
```

**main.tpl.html**

```
<h2>{{title}}</h2>

<p>You will be redirected to the second page in 5 seconds...</p>
```

**second.tpl.html**

```
<h2>{{title}}</h2>

<p>This is the second page.</p>

<p>You will be redirected to the main page in 5 seconds...</p>
```